# AVR Timer/Counter Overflow and ISR

Tags: avr, atmega

I want to create a PWM on any PIN and therefore using ISRs to achieve this. The setup I chose, working with my ATMEGA328p and Timer0 is:

```
static inline void initTimer0(void) {
    // Timer Counter Control Register B
    // Must b4 /64 or more for ISR timing
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01);

    // Timer Counter Interrupt Mask Register
    // both output compare interrupts
    TIMSK0 |= ((1 << OCIE0A) | (1 << OCIE1B));

    // Timer Counter Overflow Interrupt Enable
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << TOIE0);

    sei();
}

/* Timer/Counter0 Overflow */
// called whenever TCNT0 overflows
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
    PORTB |= (1 << 0);
    OCR0A = brightnessA;
}

// ISR fired when a match occurs
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    PORTB ^= (1 << 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    setup();
    int d = 10;

    while (1) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            _delay_ms(d);
            brightnessA = i;
        }


    }
}
```

I would have expected that the LED on PORTB would dim up but nothing happens. I think I have a gap in understanding here. I would have assumed that TIMER0_COMPA_vect ISR would fire everytime I reach the new OCR0A compare value and turn the LED of, therefore control the duty cycle.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the waveform generation mode as well in order to get this working.
Page 128 of ATmega328 [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) describes exactly how WGM bits need to be set.

> **19.5.  Output Compare Unit**
>
> The 8-bit comparator continuously compares TCNT0 with the Output Compare Registers (OCR0A and OCR0B). Whenever
> TCNT0 equals OCR0A or OCR0B, the comparator signals a match. A match
> will set the Output Compare Flag (OCF0A or OCF0B) at the next timer
> clock cycle. If the corresponding interrupt is enabled, the Output
> Compare Flag generates an Output Compare interrupt. The Output Compare
> Flag is automatically cleared when the interrupt is executed.
> Alternatively, the flag can be cleared by software by writing a '1' to
> its I/O bit location. The Waveform Generator uses the match signal to
> generate an output according to operating mode set by the WGM02,
> WGM01, and WGM00 bits and Compare Output mode (COM0x[1:0]) bits. The
> max and bottom signals are used by the Waveform Generator for handling
> the special cases of the extreme values in some modes of operation.

This means you need to configure the `TCCR0A` register as well accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember the following line?

```
DDRB |= 1 << 0;
```

Also, I don't see where you call the function `initTimer0()` in `int main()`.

You also probably want to declare `brightnessA` as `volatile`.

Comment: I don't you need to declare brightnessA as volatile unless it is *written to* in an ISR, right?

Comment: Oh sorry.. yep their is a setup function call as well where I initiate. `void setup() {
 // Set Bank B to Output
 DDRB = 0xff; 
 initTimer0();
 initUSART();
}`